# raw Value of optional type not unwrapped

Tags: swift3, enums

I am trying to unwrap the raw value of an enum type in `func toDictionary()` , but I get an error. 
How can I fix this?

```
enum ChatFeatureType: String {

  case tenants
  case leaseholders
  case residents
}

class Chat {

 var featureType: ChatFeatureType?

  init(featureType: ChatFeatureType? = nil 
     self.featureType = featureType
  }

   //download data from firebase
 init(dictionary : [String : Any]) {
      featureType = ChatFeatureType(rawValue: dictionary["featureType"] as! String)!
     }

  func toDictionary() -> [String : Any] {

     var someDict = [String : Any]()

 //  I get error  on the line below: Value of optional type 'ChatFeatureType?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
       someDict["featureType"] = featureType.rawValue ?? "" 
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `featureType` is an optional you have to add `?` or `!` as the error says

```
someDict["featureType"] = featureType?.rawValue ?? ""
```

But be aware that your code reliably crashes when you create an instance of `Chat` from a dictionary and the key does not exist because there is no case `""`.

Actually the purpose of an enum is that the value is always one of the cases. If you need an unspecified case add `none` or `unknown` or similar.

This is a safe version

```
enum ChatFeatureType: String {
     case none, tenants, leaseholders, residents
}

class Chat {

   var featureType: ChatFeatureType

   init(featureType: ChatFeatureType = .none)
       self.featureType = featureType
   }

   //download data from firebase
   init(dictionary : [String : Any]) {
       featureType = ChatFeatureType(rawValue: dictionary["featureType"] as? String) ?? .none
   }

   func toDictionary() -> [String : Any] {

      var someDict = [String : Any]()
      someDict["featureType"] = featureType.rawValue
      return someDict
  }
}
```

Comment: Now I understand. However, even if I try to force unwrap by adding the exclamation mark, it still outputs the same error: `someDict["featureType"] = featureType.rawValue!`

Comment: You have to append the exclamation mark right after `featureType`, that's the optional (`featureType!.rawValue`).